# How do I locate a file returned by lsof?

Tags: disk-usage, postgresql, proc, lsof

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 16.  I recently noticed a substantial discrepancy between what "df" reports and what "du" reports for the total size of my "/" directory.  So following this link -- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2316, I ran this

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted
[sudo] password for rails: 
postmaste 443     postgres  mem       REG              144,4          147159237 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 443     postgres  mem       REG              144,4                  0 (deleted)/VE20428-SYSV0052e2c1 (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 469     postgres  mem       REG              144,4          147159237 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 469     postgres  mem       REG              144,4                  0 (deleted)/VE20428-SYSV0052e2c1 (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 470     postgres  mem       REG              144,4          147159237 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 470     postgres  mem       REG              144,4                  0 (deleted)/VE20428-SYSV0052e2c1 (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 471     postgres  mem       REG              144,4          147159237 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 471     postgres  mem       REG              144,4                  0 (deleted)/VE20428-SYSV0052e2c1 (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 472     postgres  mem       REG              144,4          147159237 (deleted)/dev/zero (stat: No such file or directory)
postmaste 472     postgres  mem       REG              144,4                  0 (deleted)/VE20428-SYSV0052e2c1 (stat: No such file or directory)
```

but I'm confused on what the next step would be to free up disk space.  What do I need to remove/delete/truncate given the information above?

Comment: The files are deleted when `rm` (as in file entries in directories), but space allocated to them (inodes) only becomes free when no longer being used by processes as Rinzwind stated.

Comment: Are you saying that if I were to stop PostGres, I would free up "147159237" worth of space (that is the number next to those deleted files, but I don't know what units it's in)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I locate a file returned by lsof?

```
locate {filename}
```

But ... that is not the issue here. You or something deleted a bunch of files that, at the time, where in use and the system will only free it up when those are no longer in use. In this case those files belonged to postgres and it is reported as such in your `lsof`.

So either reboot the system or restart the postgres server.

Mind that is not a good idea to remove files from a system that are in use.

Comment: Note that files being deleted does not mean data is gone. Anonymous inodes are created when an application creates temp file, keeps file descriptor open, but unlinks the file. Bash for example does that with heredoc strings. So that data may still be very well in use, and rebooting may be necessary only if the system is running out of space. Otherwise, i would not recommend fixing what is not broken :)